# How can I send an entire Notes document with attachments and many RT fields via email to Outlook?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

We have an old client application from which users want to be able to send individual documents (many fields, many of them rich text with and without attachments in each) via email to people without Notes clients (or access to Notes). I am able to generate the email and include the attachments, but the body of the email is plain text and the form is very long, so it's line after line of appendText to grab the field data to include in the email. It's ugly! Is there any other way to go about this? Looking for other ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Some ideas: you could loop through doc.Items... you could use a print tool and send a PDF... you could try to webify the solution and go from there...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to write code that creates a new mail message, accesses the document you want to send, and use the [NotesDocument.RenderToRTItem](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_RENDERTORTITEM_METHOD.html) method to include the visible contents of that document in the new message.